# How to prevent the command line argument from being encoded?

Tags: python, shell, encoding, character-encoding, command-line-arguments

(Problem solved, please see the updates)

I have some files that have incorrect filenames because of encoding issues. So I want to write a python script to process it. However, I encounter a strange problem.

To better illustrate, I will use an example: the file name is displayed as `¹þÀïÂ·ÑÇ.mp3`. 
However, the following result is different:

```
# only one mp3 file is in this directory:
$ ls *mp3  | hexdump 
0000000 c2 b9 c3 be 41 cc 80 69 cc 88 41 cc 82 c2 b7 4e
0000010 cc 83 43 cc a7 2e 6d 70 33 0a                  
000001a

$ echo "¹þÀïÂ·??Ç.mp3"  | hexdump 
0000000 c2 b9 c3 be c3 80 c3 af c3 82 c2 b7 c3 91 c3 87
0000010 2e 6d 70 33 0a                                 
0000015
```

Basically, the second string (or bytes) is the one I wanted, but in my Python script, the command line arguments always give me the first string. I have no way to get around.
I notice that this only happens in Mac OS X. Hence, I suspect the argument is somehow encoded or processed by the bash/system/python. 
Here is a listing of my tools:

- Python: 2.7.2
- OS: Mac OS X 10.6.7
- Shell: `GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)`

Update: **the following code works well in my Arch Linux**, but suffers from the above problem in my Mac OS X:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys 
import os
for name in sys.argv[1:]:
    try:
        # This line does the magic:
        new_name = name.decode('utf8').encode('latin-1').decode('gbk')
        new_name_utf8 = new_name.encode('utf8')
        if name != new_name_utf8:
            print "%s -> %s" % (name, new_name_utf8)
            os.rename(name, new_name)
    except:
        print "Ignoring %s" % name
```

In shell, run:

```
$ ./the_script *mp3 # Let bash pass the file name string
```

You can run the above code for the string `¹þÀïÂ·ÑÇ.mp3`, and it should be correctly identified as `哈里路亚.mp3`. Note that you must have a UTF-8 locale and a correct Chinese font that supports Unicode to display it correctly, or check the following image:

[image: Original filename]

FYI: the GBK encoded filename does not recognize by my download program, and it is interpreted as a unicode string, which is encoded as UTF-8. The non-ascii byte in the original file is interpreted as a code point of Unicode and encoded using UTF-8, which causes the problem.

Update2: The script that are portable between Mac and Linux is now uploaded [here](https://gist.github.com/1103025).

Comment: I'd suspect the encoding happeds differently in terminal/shell itself and Python has no control over it. Can you do an example where a Python script calls your own Python script via subprocess call and passes the command-line argument as a function argument, instead of trying to do it directly from the terminal.

Comment: Is your script iterating through a directory itself, or are you passing the filenames (either individually or as a wildcard) to the script on the command line?

Comment: @John I am passing arguments. One observation is, I can use both strings to `open` the file.

Comment: Why is the particular byte sequence important to you? Both those dumps are UTF-8 strings, only the second, shorter one is precomposed (it uses the direct codepoints for accented characters), while the first, longer one has separate combining marks.

Comment: Could you post your python code? Have you tried using different shells, e.g. `csh`, or `sh`?

Comment: @John Because it just matters to me: the encoded UTF8 stream has no meaning at all. I have to use the byte stream of the correct (2nd) one to process. In this sense, the two version may be printed to output as the same string, but totally different to me.

Comment: @William Niu Please check the original post. I tried `fish`, `csh`, `zsh`, no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that MacOS X's default filesystem changes all filenames you give it to an unusual normalization form which does not use precomposed characters. The unicodedata Python module allows converting between these forms, for example:

```
import unicodedata
print len(unicodedata.normalize("NFD", u"\u00C7"))
print len(unicodedata.normalize("NFC", u"\u00C7"))
```

These print 2 and 1, respectively.

Comment: Exactly the answer I am looking for! Now the problem is solved!!! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
J=1
for I in * ; do
    mv -i "$I" "$J"
    J=$((J+1))
done
```

This will iterate through all the files and rename them to sequential numbers, so you get rid of the problematic characters.

Comment: This does not solve the problem, I want to **detect** the original file name. Plz check my update.